# phonegap + android Touch events Error singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport False

Tags: android, cordova, touch

I'm using cordova2.7, android 4+, I have a problem in Touch events on Samsung, same app runs on HTC onex without errors, this error cause a very slow touch event response.
The problem is specially be shown when use free hand drawing - feature of my app.

I'm in this error for two days now.

mainly

singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE

lead to

Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.

logcat

06-24 10:12:38.013: D/DroidGap(23854): Resuming the App
06-24 10:12:38.052: D/DroidGap(23854): Paused the application!
06-24 10:12:43.443: D/DroidGap(23854): Resuming the App
06-24 10:12:47.599: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:12:47.599: W/webview(23854): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
06-24 10:12:49.950: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:12:51.763: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:12:51.763: W/webview(23854): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
06-24 10:13:21.271: D/DroidGap(23854): Paused the application!
06-24 10:13:23.302: D/DroidGap(23854): Resuming the App
06-24 10:13:24.880: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:13:24.880: W/webview(23854): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
06-24 10:13:26.552: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:13:28.310: V/webview(23854):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
06-24 10:13:28.310: W/webview(23854): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.

please, what can i do ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by listening to 'touchstart' event, and preventingDefault.

```
$('.element').on('touchstart', function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem, though, it also cancel all the scroll events if there is any in the '.element' element. In order to solve that, I had to use the iScroll component on the element.

Comment: I noticed that it also works when binding to 'touchmove' event.